# Iterate over a random timestamp column in Python

Tags: python, loops, csv, timestamp, col

I have a huge file, where the columns are randomly sequenced and I was able to use pandas to read a specific timestamp column.

```
with open(<file name>, 'r') as in_file:
     b = pandas.read_csv(in_file,usecols=["<Timestamp Column Name>"],parse_dates=[0])

c = b.to_csv(header=None,index=False)
print c
```

Sample values are:

```
2016-11-26 16:12:00
2016-11-30 09:19:00
2016-11-28 17:30:00
2016-11-30 14:50:00
2016-11-26 21:39:00
2016-01-12 11:14:00
2016-11-27 09:39:00
2016-11-28 06:50:00
2016-11-26 14:08:00
2016-11-30 12:42:00
2016-11-26 11:01:00
2016-11-25 08:23:00
```

Now I'm trying to loop through this column to achieve a count. If I use a simple for loop, it reads every digit like a string, which is of no use. Appreciate some help.

Comment: You want a count of all the lines in `c`?

Comment: What type of count ? you have a specific output in mind ? if so please update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
text='''2016-11-26 16:12:00
2016-11-30 09:19:00
2016-11-28 17:30:00
2016-11-30 14:50:00
2016-11-26 21:39:00
2016-01-12 11:14:00
2016-11-27 09:39:00
2016-11-28 06:50:00
2016-11-26 14:08:00
2016-11-30 12:42:00
2016-11-26 11:01:00
2016-11-25 08:23:00'''

l = text.splitlines()
```

or :

```
l = text.split('\n')
```

or read from csv file:

```
with open('you_data.csv') as f:
    l = f.readlines()
```

out:

```
print(l)
['2016-11-26 16:12:00', '2016-11-30 09:19:00', '2016-11-28 17:30:00', '2016-11-30 14:50:00', '2016-11-26 21:39:00', '2016-01-12 11:14:00', '2016-11-27 09:39:00', '2016-11-28 06:50:00', '2016-11-26 14:08:00', '2016-11-30 12:42:00', '2016-11-26 11:01:00', '2016-11-25 08:23:00']
```

just split by line break use splitlines, this will return a list

Comment: This helped me navigate through the data and convert that into dates, to achieve what I wanted. I was looking to group certain dates and take count for each of them.